# LG 27UD88-W usable like a docking station / kvm switch?

Tags: display, displayport, kvm-switch, usb-c, lg-monitor

Does setup shown in the picture work? I mean can I switch between laptop and desktop on the monitor routing mouse input and sound correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't work as you desire.

With your setup you connect only video and audio to your desktop, mouse and keyboard will be connected to the laptop only (it works only through USB-C port).

> The USB port on the product functions as a USB hub.
>   Please connect the USB C-C or USB C-A cable to the 
>   PC.

From http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=UFGkS31eyTryXnpFzPDkxw

---

What will work :

- You can get everything through USB-C
- you can connect audio & video through HDMI or DP
- you can switch audio & video source on your monitor (you can see your desktop on monitor and use the mouse on your laptop)
- you can unplug the USB-C cable from laptop and plug it into desktop computer to use mouse there. (of course this way your laptop won't be charged)

Comment: Do you have any solution for this setup (T480, RX 500/ASRock Z370 Pro4) - maybe a different monitor or some kind of switch?

Comment: I image that may work with an extra manual step of switching the usb-c cable coming from the monitor? i mean plugging it out of the T480 and pluggin it into this cable coming from my desktops mainboard:  https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN/dp/B074K318JK

Comment: Taking away the mouse/keyboard (i could solve this by using Logitech Easy-Switch) looking only at audio, video and charging, it works as i expect?

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

as option you can switch audio and video source on your monitor via DDC monitor control
see https://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net etc

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel